# why is torsion free needed

Tags: modules

This is from P134 of Rotman's Homological Algebra book.

If R is a PID, then every torsion-free R-module is flat.

Proof. If R is a PID, then every finitely generated R-module M is a direct sum of cyclic modules. If M is torsion-free, then it is a direct sum of copies of R.

So if M is not torsion-free, we cannot conclude that each cyclic module is isomorphic to R? Why? Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: If $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Z}\oplus \left( \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}\right)$, then $M$ is a direct sum of cyclic modules over $R$ but is not a sum of copies of $R$

Comment: Hi Dldier! Thank you for the example. I understand this. But how being torsion-free gives us each cyclic module isomorphic to R? Would you please shed some lights for me?

Comment: If $C$ is a cyclic $R$-module, generated  by $a$, you have a surjective morphism $R\to C$, $\,\lambda\mapsto \lambda a$, and if  $C$ is torsion free, this morphism is also injective.

Comment: @Bernard  do you mean if R is torsion free?

Comment: Why, yes, of course, a ring is torsion free as a module over itself. Actually, any free module is torsion free.

Comment: @Bernard Please let me know if I understand you correctly, thank you!!! :  C is a cyclic direct summand of M and M is torsion free. Then there is that surjective morphism you mentioned....

Comment: Any submodule of a torsion-free module is torsion-free, whether a direct summand or not. What's the problem with the surjective morphism?

Comment: @ Bernard   no problem at all. I just didn't copy down what you wrote about the morphism.  thx. clear now!